# Can the Haglin's Satchel add any orb to your deck?

Tags: peglin

The description for [Haglin's Satche](https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Haglin%27s_Satchel)l says it "Randomly adds 2 orbs to your deck, then randomly upgrades orbs 4 times."

Are there any limits to which orbs the Haglin's Satchel can add to your deck? For example, can it grant event-specific orbs like the [Egg](https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Egg?so=search) or [Orboros](https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Orboros)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of v0.8.9](https://steamcommunity.com/games/1296610/announcements/detail/3627116251908573015), the Haglin's Satchel cannot grant event-specific orbs.

> Haglin's Satchel no longer grants orbs that should only be obtainable via scenarios.